# Migration to material design - Should we use Toolbar or ActionBar

Tags: android, material-design

Currently, I'm in the process of migrating a holo designed app to material designed app.

I came across the following article : http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

> In this release, Android introduces a new Toolbar widget. This is a
>   generalization of the Action Bar pattern that gives you much more
>   control and flexibility. Toolbar is a view in your hierarchy just like
>   any other, making it easier to interleave with the rest of your views,
>   animate it, and react to scroll events. You can also set it as your
>   Activity’s action bar, meaning that your standard options menu actions
>   will be display within it.

The above text doesn't seem clear to me. My first impression is that.

1. `Toolbar` is more powerful than `ActionBar`. It can do all what `ActionBar` can do, yet provide some other extra functionality.
2. Google seems to want to promote `Toolbar` over `ActionBar`

I was wondering, how can we decide, whether when should we use `ActionBar`, and when should we use `Toolbar`.

What I want to achieve is something similar to latest Google Play Store app.

### Navigation drawer is under action bar

[image]

### There is collapseActionView

I can specific my menu as

```
<item 
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"
    android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/collapsible_searchtext"
    android:icon="?attr/actionBarSearchIcon"/>
```

[image]

I came across latest Google Play Newsstand

### Navigation drawer covers over action bar

[image]

1. If I want feature ***Navigation drawer covers over action bar***, is `Toolbar` is a must?
2. If I want to have only feature ***Navigation drawer is under action bar*** and ***There is collapseActionView***, willl `ActionBar` be sufficient enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActionBars *are* ToolBars (just created and added to the contentView for you) so the difference is a little immaterial.

Just a reminder that Nav drawer over the action bar is the Material design guidelines per the [Material Design checklist](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/material-design-on-android-checklist.html) and should be the only model you use (much discussion has occured on the [official Android App Design Google+ community](https://plus.google.com/communities/116667001535376136065) which has confirmed that fact and that all Google apps are moving to that standard).

Comment: Thanks for the valuable input. My personal feeling that Nav drawer over the action bar has one major drawback. Previously, I can toggle the visibility of the drawer, by tapping the **same** location again and again. Now, I'm puzzling, **what I suppose to do, to hide the drawer, without performing any selection**.

Comment: Pressing back, tapping outside, or pulling it shut? Opening and closing the drawer without taking an action shouldn't be a case you are optimizing for